# Vue Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

I'm working on a `Vue + typescript` project. I want to use `process.env.var_name` to adjust the project is in development mode or production mode, just like

```
const isProduct = process.env.APP_ENV === "prod";
```

; however I got an error below. I never meet this error before, so could any one give me a clue why this would happen so I can try to figure out what happend in the project and then fix it.[image]

Comment: have you solved it? facing the same issue

Comment: Did this happen after upgrading your dependenices? Then have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944663/uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined-after-upgrading-from-vue-cli-v4

Answer (score 165, accepted):

If you are using Vite, use `import.meta.env` instead, `process.env` is removed.

And make sure variables start with `VITE_` in `.env` file.

```
VITE_SOME_KEY=123
```

more
https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Comment: I'm using the Vite that came with Vue 3 and had the same problem. As you mentioned I used import.meta.env instead of process.env and it worked.

Comment: FYI y'all, This is not recommended for storing secrets variables, "VITE_*" variables should not contain any sensitive information as said in the same linked documetation.

Comment: completely missing from the https://cli.vuejs.org/guide documentation.

Comment: @AnjanBiswas because it protects your application from misusing/revealing environment variables that it's not supposed to have access to.

Comment: I am confused: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html says you can still use NODE_ENV in .env files

Answer (score 12):

A workaround that I found was have the vite.config.js file like this

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/

export default ({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "");
  return defineConfig({
    define: {
      "process.env": env,
    },
    plugins: [vue()],
    server: {
      host: true,
      port: 8080,
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Use loadEnv from vite and then define the "process.env" variable to point to env.

Comment: This worked fine for me. I prefer still using process.env to keep my code syntax intact.

Comment: Please note that **this will statically replace each instance of `process.env` with the _entire env object_**.

Comment: as @DarrylNoakes said this one will replace each static use of '`process.env` with a string like `{"ALLUSERSPROFILE":"C:\\ProgramData","APPDATA":...` so I had to use `"process.env.NODE_ENV": '"' + mode + '"'` in order to replace `process.env.NODE_ENV` in `vue.runtime.esm.js` with the actual value `production` or `development`

Answer (score 9):

You can use `if (import.meta.env.PROD) ...` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: { 
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  },
  define: {
    'process.env': {}
  }
})
```

Comment: Try to add description for the written code.

Comment: I read this does not work in prod builds

Comment: This way only replace process.env with empty object!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

In vite react app

```
const { data } = await axios.post(
    `${import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_API}/register`,
    {
      name,
      email,
      password,
    }
```

use
import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_API like that

and in .env file use VITE_REACT_APP_API=http://localhost:8000/api

Erros will be solved

Answer (score 1):

***You will get this error when referencing a variable that does not exist.*** 
**Here is the solution;**

```
mounted () {
  window.process = {
    env: {
       NODE_ENV: 'development'
    }
}
```

*If you use it on the page where you got an error, your error will be fixed.*

Answer (score 0):

Env's variables must start with `VUE_APP_`, so try to change `APP_ENV` into `VUE_APP_ENV`.
About the CORS error you have to enable your FE from your BE.

Comment: Tried your solution, but not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Vite and and after all setup setup it says process is not defined.
then i got a Solution.

you can access the key like this:-

```js
//like this you can access the key in vite

const API_URl = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_KEY}&s=titanic`;


//And Here is the way to define the key in .env file

VITE_APP_API_KEY=5588hfhf
```

const API_URl = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_KEY}&s=titanic`;

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
import "dotenv";

const apiKey= import.meta.env.VITE_YOUR_API_KEY;

console.log(apiKey);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

I have a quasar project before and this one works for me.

I installed the `dotenv` library by running the yarn command

```
yarn add --dev dotenv
```

Please let me know.